# Mule - finding the sum of the values of xml elements

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to find the sume of the xml elements in mule. The input xml looks like this :

```
<message:MessageGroup
xmlns:message="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message"
xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic"
xmlns:common="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/common"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/generic http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXGenericData.xsd http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message http://www.sdmx.org/docs/2_0/SDMXMessage.xsd">
<Header xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message">
    <ID>none</ID>
    <Test>false</Test>
    <Truncated>false</Truncated>
    <Prepared>2017-08-28T05:35:50</Prepared>
    <Sender id="ABS">
        <Name xml:lang="en">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
        <Name xml:lang="fr">Australian Bureau of Statistics</Name>
    </Sender>
</Header>
<DataSet
    keyFamilyURI="http://stat.data.abs.gov.au/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetKeyFamily/CPI">
    <KeyFamilyRef>CPI</KeyFamilyRef>
    <Series>
        <SeriesKey>
            <Value concept="MEASURE" value="3" />
            <Value concept="REGION" value="50" />
            <Value concept="INDEX" value="10001" />
            <Value concept="TSEST" value="10" />
            <Value concept="FREQUENCY" value="Q" />
        </SeriesKey>
        <Attributes>
            <Value concept="TIME_FORMAT" value="P3M" />
        </Attributes>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2001-Q1</Time>
            <ObsValue value="6" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2001-Q2</Time>
            <ObsValue value="6.1" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2001-Q3</Time>
            <ObsValue value="2.5" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2001-Q4</Time>
            <ObsValue value="3.1" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2002-Q1</Time>
            <ObsValue value="3" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2002-Q2</Time>
            <ObsValue value="2.8" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2002-Q3</Time>
            <ObsValue value="3.2" />
        </Obs>
        <Obs>
            <Time>2002-Q4</Time>
            <ObsValue value="2.9" />
        </Obs>
            </Series>
    <Annotations>
        <common:Annotation>
            <common:AnnotationTitle>Statistical usage warning
            </common:AnnotationTitle>
            <common:AnnotationText>
                ABS.Stat beta is continuing to be developed. Data will be updated as soon
                as possible following its 11:30 am release on the ABS website.
            </common:AnnotationText>
        </common:Annotation>
    </Annotations>
</DataSet>
```

Here I need to do sum of the elements :  which is inside : **MessageGroup.DataSet.Series.*Obs**. Tried doing using dataweave but was unsuccessful. While using dataweave I am not able to value of . Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As values are attributes of ObsValue tag use @ sign to get attribute value like,

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
sum (payload.MessageGroup.DataSet.Series.*Obs.ObsValue.@value)
```

Output = 29.6

Hope this helps